# Can't reload background image when dismissing

Tags: ios, swift

I need to reload a background image in the MainVC when the user chooses it from the ViewController that will be dismissed but I can't figure out how. Any idea?
Ps. In the MainVC I have a collectionView, every cell contain another collectionView and these collectionViews have a custom cell.
When the user chooses a background image that image is passed to the custom cell and should be set as background.

Protocol

```
protocol ThemeDelegate {
    func handlePassThemeData(data: UIImage)
}
```

MainVC

```
class MainVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource, ThemeDelegate {

    var currentTheme = UIImage(named: "4")!
    let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.register(QuoteCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        collectionView.register(FeaturedCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: featuredReuseIdentifier)
        collectionView.register(AuthorCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: authorReuseIdentifier)
        return collectionView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad
        setUpViews()
        setupNavigationBarItems()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if indexPath.item == 0 {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! QuoteCell
            createGradientLayer(bounds: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.frame.width, height: cell.frame.height), cell: cell)
            cell.delegate = self
            cell.imageToPass = currentTheme
            return cell
        } else if indexPath.item == 1 {
            ...
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if indexPath.item == 0 {
            return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height / 1.5)
        } else if indexPath.item == 1 {
            return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height / 1.95)
        } else {
            return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 160)
        }
    }

    func setupNavigationBarItems() {
        let themesButton = setUpBarButton(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "themes_icon_color"))
        themesButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleThemesTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: themesButton)
    }

    func setUpViews() {
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.delegate = self  
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.anchors(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor)
    }

    func handlePassThemeData(data: UIImage) {
        self.currentTheme = data
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    @objc func handleThemesTapped() {
        let themesVc = ThemesVC(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: themesVc)
        themesVc.delegate = self                
        navigationController?.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

MainVC Cell with ColletionView

```
class QuoteCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var imageToPass = UIImage(named: "2")!
    let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.register(QuoteSubCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        return collectionView
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setUpViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! QuoteSubCell
        cell.quote = quotes[indexPath.item]

        cell.setupCell(with: imageToPass)
        return cell
    }

    func setUpViews() {
        addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.anchors(top: nameLabel.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor)
    }
}
```

CustomCell

```
class QuoteSubCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var backgroundImage: UIImageView = {
        let view = UIImageView()
        view.clipsToBounds = true
        view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        view.image = UIImage(named: "2")
        return view
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setUpViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setupCell(with image: UIImage) {
        backgroundImage.image = image
    }

    func setUpViews() {
        contentView.addSubview(backgroundImage)
        backgroundImage.anchors(top: contentView.topAnchor, left: contentView.leftAnchor, bottom: contentView.bottomAnchor, right: contentView.rightAnchor)
    }
}
```

ThemesVC where the user chooses the background

```
class ThemesVC: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var delegate: ThemeDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        setUpViews()
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ThemeCell
        cell.backgroundImage.image = themeCell.backgroundImages[indexPath.item]
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        return cell
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        delegate?.handlePassThemeData(data: themeCell.backgroundImages[indexPath.item])        
        self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func setUpViews() {
        collectionView.register(ThemeCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: whitePoint, alpha: 1)
        collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you get into ThemesVC? How is it presented?
You need to use delegation or callbacks.
Post the code where you present ThemesVC.

Comment: @Starsky I added how the ThemesVC is presented and also a delegation

Comment: Why do you have `cell.delegate = self` in the `cellForItemAt` in the MainVC? What delegate does the cell have? It is the ThemesVC which only has the delegate (ThemeDelegate).

Comment: Also, I don't see where your `@objc func handleThemesTapped()` gets called? Who is calling this function?

Comment: @Starsky `cell.delegate = self` is just a delegate for a popup in `QuoteCell`. I added what `@objc func handleThemesTapped()` refers to, it presents `ThemesVC`.

Comment: Well, it is hard to say why this isn't working for you. Put breakpoints, see which parts of the code work, and which doesn't. If any delegate methods for the collectionView don't work, then debug and see why. Does the delegate `handlePassThemeData(data:)` gets called?

Comment: @Starsky yes it works well

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right.

```
class MainVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource, ThemeDelegate {

    //MARK: Properties
    var currentTheme = UIImage(named: "defaultImage")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpViews()
    }

    func setUpViews() {
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.anchors(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor)
    }
    func handlePassThemeData(data: UIImage) {
        self.currentTheme = data //override your variable with the new image
        self.collectionView.reloadData() //reload the collectionView, to apply the change
    }

    @objc func handleThemesTapped() {
        let themesVc = ThemesVC(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        themesVc.delegate = self       
        //no need to instantiate a new navigationController. Just push to the current one, if you want the animation from right, and not from bottom-up.         
        navigationController?.pushViewController(themesVc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Delegates should always be weak referenced.

```
class ThemesVC: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    weak var delegate: ThemeDelegate?

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        delegate?.handlePassThemeData(data: themeCell.backgroundImages[indexPath.item])
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Also, you don't need to create a static variable inside the cell. Instead, pass your `currentImage` to your cell's variable `imageToPass` in the method `cellForItemAt`.

```
class QuoteCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var imageToPass = UIImage(named: "defaultImage")//pass this image to the cells inside the collectionView

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setUpViews()
    }

    func setUpViews() {
        addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.anchors(top: nameLabel.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor)
    }
}
```

Finally, your subCells should show your image:

```
class QuoteSubCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var backgroundImage: UIImageView = {
        let view = UIImageView()
        view.clipsToBounds = true
        view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        view.image = QuoteSubCell.chosenTheme
        return view
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setUpViews()
    }

    private func setUpViews() {
        contentView.addSubview(backgroundImage)
        backgroundImage.anchors(top: contentView.topAnchor, left: contentView.leftAnchor, bottom: contentView.bottomAnchor, right: contentView.rightAnchor)
    }

    func setupCell(with image: UIImage) { //use this setup function inside "cellForItemAt" method, where you will pass the `imageToPass` image.

        backgroundImage.image = image
    }
}
```

- **UPDATE:**

`cellForItemAt` inside **MainVC**:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if indexPath.item == 0 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! QuoteCell
        createGradientLayer(bounds: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.frame.width, height: cell.frame.height), cell: cell)
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.imageToPass = currentTheme //here you pass the image the 1st time
        return cell
    } else if indexPath.item == 1 {
        ...
    }
}
```

`cellForItemAt` inside **QuoteCell**:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! QuoteSubCell
    cell.quote = quotes[indexPath.item]
    cell.setupCell(with: imageToPass) //here you pass the image the second time
    return cell
}
```

If you're still unable to make it work, I will ask you to share the code from the `cellForItemAt` methods from the both collectionViews.

Comment: I think I did everything you told me but it doesn't work

Comment: Your `MainVC` and `ThemesVC` have IBOutlets? Is it all being setup programatically? You must understand that when you initialize a new `MainVC`, it is a completely different instance than your currently used MainVC. Here you do: `let main = MainVC()
imageToPass = main.currentTheme`. This is not correct. You need to pass `currentTheme` inside the `cellForItemAt` method. I will update my answer.

Comment: I have no IBOutlets, it's all programmatic. I added "cell.imageToPass = currentTheme". But it still doesn't work. I updated my code above. CellForItemAt isn't called when I choose an image in ThemesVC, can't it be the problem?

Comment: You mean `didSelectItemAt` isn't called inside ThemesVC? Did you set `collectionView.delegate = self` in the `viewDidLoad()`?

Comment: `didSelectItemAt` in ThemeVC is called. But I added some breakpoints and from when I choose a theme the image passes in `MainVC` then in `imageToPass` in the `QuoteCell` and then stops, it's not passed from `cellForItemAt` to the func `setupCell(with: imageToPass)`.

Comment: Did you set your `collectionView.datasource = self` in `QuoteCell`?
Next time, post the entire classes, otherwise, if you take a look back, I am just asking you "did you do this, did you do that"? Is that a secret code you're afraid to share? It makes helping you much harder and you would get a quicker help if I saw everything, but not just pieces that you think are important.